# Copy references to new array list and delete in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, clone

I have one array list, studentsList, like the following:

```
class Student{
String name;
List<Subject> subjects;
}
```

I want to copy references to these objects in another list say studentsListCopy. When I make any changes in the Student objects in studentsListCopy, say change the name, it should also reflect in the original list but if I delete the student object from studentsListCopy, it should not get deleted from the original list. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Make a clone of the list but not the elements of the list (both lists should "point to" the same elements).

Comment: there's no concept of deleting refereces in java, you can assign null to reference and it will be garbage collected at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new List with the Objects e.g. `new ArrayList<>(subjects)` and do as you please.

Comment: I tried this but when I remove subjects from studentsListCopy, they get removed from studentsList as well.

Comment: I am iterating through the subjects in studentsListCopy using Iterator and removing some subjects, those objects are being from from subjects list of studentsList as well.

Comment: @MobileAppDeveloper You should add that piece of code into your starting post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to simply create a new `List` (sub-implementation should be used) having your original list as an argument.

Any changes to the elements within any of the containers (original list or its copy), will affect the object itself as you are manipulating the referenced object and deleting or inserting elements within any of those containers won't affect the other as they are totally separated:

```java
class Student {
  String name;
  List<Subject> subjects;

  private void someMethod() {
    // create a shallow copy
    List<Subject> copy = new ArrayList<>(subjects);
    // edit the contained elements
    copy.get(0).setSomeProperty();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<student> studentsListCopy = new ArrayList<student>();

for(int i=0;i<studentList;i++)
{
   studentsListCopy.add(studentList[i])
}
```

were you perhaps looking for something like this?

Comment: [There is no append method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: excuse my java, it has gotten rusty.

Answer (score 0):

Create an unmodifiable list from your list. In this way you can edit list elements' properties and you cannot remove elements from list. Like below:

```
List<Student> editStudentList = Collections.unmodifiableList(yourStudentList);
```